# Calculating eigenvectors where there is only 1 non zero number in matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am attempting to find the equilibrium points of a nonlinear system and I am getting the following jacobian matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1.5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I have found the eigenvalues as 1 and 1.5 but am at a loss when attempting to find the eigenvectors for each. For eigenvalue equal to 1 i get the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0.5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        v1  \\
        v2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Which using gauss jordan becomes:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & | & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & | & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

From here I am lost as what to do because every answer becomes zero. When throwing the jacobian matrix into wolfram alpha, the vector for eigenvalue equals to 1 is:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there some sort of trick I am missing?

Comment: It's not true that "every answer becomes zero".  [This may help](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702665/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda = 1$, we have the RREF of $[A -I]v_1 = 0$ as:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 \\
 0  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Lets write this out to understand what it is telling us. We have:

$$0a + 1 b = 0 \\ 0a + 0b = 0$$

If we choose $b = 1$, can we satisfy this system? No. If we choose $b = 0$, this would give us a zero eigenvector, which is not allowed. What is we chose $a = 1$ and $b=0$. Hey, that satisfies the system and gives us a non-zero eigenvector. This is also called the null space of the matrix.

This means we have $a = 1 $, so we can choose $b = 0$, so $v_1 = (1, 0)$. We could have also chosen $v_1 = (-1, 0)$. Try using $3/2$ instead of $1.5$ in WA and see what happens. Regardless, both answers are acceptable as eigenvectors are not unique.

Do you see how that vector satisfies the system and is **not** a zero eigenvector?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wolfram alpha actually says that the result should be v1 = (-1,0) . Also, where did you get a=1 from?

Comment: Hey, I know I've already accepted this answer and it has helped me, but I'm still having trouble connecting a=1 here. If I was to create simultaneous equations where v1 = (a,b), it would result in v1 = (0, 1). If someone could help me to further understand this that would be great.

Comment: I know it says not to add comments about thanking people, but you are a legend. Thanks :)