# Eigenvectors of the Zero Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following matrix: $ \begin{pmatrix}
   -1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $.

I have to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this matrix, and I have calculated that this matrix has an eigenvalue of $-1$ with multiplicity $2$
However, here is where my problem comes in:

To calculate the eigenvector, I need to use:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
   -1-\lambda & 0 \\          
    0 & -1-\lambda\ \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $$

Multiply it by

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
                               x \\
                               y \\
                               \end{pmatrix} $$

and set it equal to $$ \lambda\ \begin{pmatrix}
                               x \\
                               y \\
                               \end{pmatrix} $$

Using my value of $\lambda = -1$, I end up having the following: $ \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\          
    0 & 0 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

which equals $ \begin{pmatrix}
                               -x \\
                               -y \\
                               \end{pmatrix}. $

However, apparently I am meant to get an eigenvector of $  \begin{pmatrix}
                               1 \\
                               0 \\
                               \end{pmatrix} $. I have no idea where I am going wrong

Comment: As you've noted, you need to set $AX=\lambda X$, but you've done $(A-\lambda I)X=\lambda X$.

Comment: Tip: Put the periods *before* the ending `$$`.

Comment: @Amzoti - surely my value of λ ensures that any $v_i$ satisfies     $[A−λI]vi=0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can read the eigenvalues and eigenvectors just by inspection. Notice that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
=
-I
$$
Now think for a minute. This matrix effectively just multiplies the input by $-1$. What eigenvectors could it have? Recall that eigenvectors are special directions along which matrix multiplication acts just like multiplying the input by some scalar $\lambda$. Guess what! We already know that this matrix simply multiplies the input by $-1$, so any direction will do (every non-zero vector is an eigenvector of this matrix).  What about eigenvalues $\lambda$? Well, you've probably guessed it: $\lambda=-1$.

Pick a pair of linearly independent vectors to describe the whole eigenspace and you are done with no calculation whatsoever. I would pick the simplest pair imaginable, that is:
$$
x_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
x_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
But really, you could have picked a different one, such as:

$$
x_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
x_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\5\end{pmatrix}
$$

It makes no difference as long as they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

User uraf's answer is supernal, but if you wanted to solve this more methodically, then you could solve $(A - (1)I)$**x** $=0$ traditionally, as explained in these analogous questions :

[Eigenvector when all terms in that column are zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/779916/53259)

[What to do with an empty column in the basis of the null space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/702665/53259)

$0$**x** $= 0 \iff 0x + 0y = 0$, so any $x, y$ satisfy this equation. In particular, the elementary basis vectors do.